# What differences are there between addresses using & operator and without & operator?

Tags: c, pointers

I have faced two different addresses for a pointer variable.I don't know what they mean.Why was there two different addresses for two outputs?

```
char *name = "John";
printf("is stored at %p\n",name ); //output that is showed "is stored at 0x558b8c21e9c4"
printf("print on the screen %p\n",&name);//output that is showed "print on the screen 0x7ffd8b9be710"
```

Comment: The first one is the adress the pointer holds. The second is the adress of the pointer itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `name` contains the address of the string literal `"John"`.

So this call

```
printf("is stored at %p\n",name );
```

outputs the address of the first character of the string literal.

The expression `&name` contains the address of the variable `name` and has the type `char **` instead of the type `char *` So the second call of `printf` outputs the address of the variable `name` itself instead of the address of the string literal.

You should cast outputted pointers to the type `void *`. For example

```
printf("is stored at %p\n", ( void * )name );
```